# How do mobile phone apps handle OAuth login page redirects?

Tags: ios, android-studio, xamarin, ionic-framework, oauth

Websites nowadays handle logins via an **OAuth Server**. With OAuth, user login screens are provided by the OAuth server, which the website is **redirected to**. User types in their credential on this website, not directly on the Web App anymore.

On a mobile app, how does this redirect work? Does the app launches its own browser? Do they use the system browser or their own embedded browser?

PS: I come from the Web world. I am building a Angular App that needs to be ported to mobile via the Ionic Framework. Though my question is rather genereic to any Mobile Apps (Xamarin, Android,IOS, etc...)

Comment: For this approach you can use 2 different servers 1st: Authentication Server for Auth API's 2nd: Other API's. and use `AuthGuard` as you said you use angular to guard your routes.

Comment: On iOS apps should use `SFSafariViewController` in the app to present the OAuth web pages; this provides a better UX than being bounced out the web browser and then back to the app.  The app registers a URI with iOS (Say my app://) and the OAuth process uses that as the return URL to provide the token to the app.

Comment: @Paulw11 I wonder if this thing is available in `Ionic Framework`. I think you are talking about Native IOS application!!

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/safari-view-controller